# How to wrap jQuery content in H tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

having a bit of trouble getting `<h3>` tags around some content I'm appending in jQuery.

Pretty simple really, each div with the class `.gallery-icon` gets its containing anchor `title` attribute appended to it.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".gallery-icon").each(function() {

        $(this).append($(this).find('a').attr('title'));

    });

});
```

Problem I'm facing is the `title` just gets inserted without any tags, i.e.:

```html
<div class="gallery-icon">
  <a title="Yadda!" href="http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1343964507704_8609552.png"><img src="http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1343964507704_8609552.png" alt="Yadda!"></a>
  Yadda!</div>
```

Note: `Yadda!` is just sitting in the gallery-icon div without any tags. I want it wrapped in `h3`'s.

So ideally it'd read:

```html
<div class="gallery-icon">
  <a title="Yadda!" href="http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1343964507704_8609552.png"><img src="http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1343964507704_8609552.png" alt="Yadda!"></a>
  <h3>Yadda!</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
$(this).append($(this).find('a').attr('title'));
```

to this:

```
$(this).append($('<h3/>', {text: $(this).find('a').attr('title')}));
```

or this:

```
$('<h3/>', {
   text: $(this).find('a').attr('title')
}).appendTo(this);
```

```js
$(".gallery-icon").each(function(i, elem) {
  $('<h3/>', {
    text:$(this).find('a').attr('title')
  }).appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="gallery-icon">
  <a title="Yadda!" href="http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1343964507704_8609552.png">
    <img src="http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1343964507704_8609552.png" alt="Yadda!">
  </a></div>
```

---

Even this can be done:

```
$(this).append('<h3>'+ $(this).find('a').attr('title') + '</h3>');
```